# Error executing procedure with pymssql

Tags: python-2.7, flask, pymssql

I have the following query (inside a function) that I call via curl in a webservice developed with Flask.

```
def DefineAppRoot(self):
    try:
        from os import listdir, remove, environ
        import pymssql
        environ['TDSVER'] = "7.0"
        mssql_db = pymssql.connect(server='SERVER', user='USER', password='PASS', as_dict=True)
        cur = mssql_db.cursor()

    except:
        logger.error("ror: [ERROR] Connect error SQL SERVER: %s" % sys.exc_info()[0])
        return json.dumps({"code": 102, "message": "Connect error SQL SERVER:"},sort_keys=True)

    try:
        cur.callproc('spws_ApPDelete', ("%s", "%s")% (self.domain, self.project))
        mssql_db.commit()
        cur.close()
    except Exception, e:
        logger.error("ror: [ERROR] not possible to run a query: %s" % sys.exc_info()[0])

logger.info("ror: [INFO] OK ")
return json.dumps({"code": 0, "message": "OK:"},sort_keys=True)
```

`

But I get this message here:

```
<type 'exceptions.TypeError'>
```

Which is related to my query:

`cur.callproc('spws_ApPDelete', ("%s", "%s")% (self.domain, self.project))`

Comment: Why is it tagged under RPyC?

Comment: sorry, I put the tag unintentionally.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using the insert this way:

```
cur.callproc('spws_ApPDelete', (self.domain, self.project))
```